# Accessing element in dict in jinja2 with a key in context passed by jinja

Tags: python, django, jinja2

So I have this data stucture

```
data ={
    "status": 200,
     "loan_amount": 500,
     "repayment": {
             200: {7: 250, 14:300},
             500: {7: 550, 14: 600}
           }
     }
```

Now I want to access the repayment with loan amount in jinja template

```
from jinja2 import Template

template = Template("Your repayment options are {{repayment.{{loan_amount}} }}")

template.render(data)
```

am getting a syntax error. 
Do anyone knows how to access that .   Not I don't know loan_amount in advance thats why I want to access it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> from jinja2 import Template
>>> 
>>> template = Template("Your repayment options are {{repayment[loan_amount] }}")
>>> template.render(data)
u'Your repayment options are {14: 600, 7: 550}'
```

`jinja2`, somewhat like javascript, [doesn't really distinguish between item access via like `x['foo']` vs `x.foo`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#variables).  So, I just used the former method rather than the latter (as inside the `{{...}}`, everything is already "dereferenced" by jinja).

Comment: It doesn't work. So in simple I want to get this result {{repayment[500]}} or {{repayment.500}}. But for some reason it want to get the key from loan_amount since {{loan_amount}} is 500 I want something like this {{repayment.{{loan_amount}}}}

Comment: @user2388404 -- I'm not sure I understand.  In your example data, `loan_amount` is `500` and `repayment[500]` is `{14: 600, 7: 550}` as is demonstrated in my example.

Comment: loan_amount is 500   repayment[500] is {14: 600, 7:500}

Comment: sorry, I'm still not understanding.  `repayment[500]` is `{14: 600, 7: 550}` in your example code.  Maybe I should take a step back -- What string do you want to get from `template.render(data)`?

Comment: so lets says data is {"loan_amount": 500, "repayment": {500: {14: 600, 7:500}}  I want to do this template = Template("{{repayment.{{loan_amount}}}}") template.render(data)   without referencing the 500 direct

Comment: sorry  I didn't read your answer correctly . Yep its correct thanks